# Auto-login user after Registration in Identityserver4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

our registration process is an Angular2 application that calls an .NET Core API. After registration we would like to automatically login the user in Identityserver4, instead of simply redirecting the user to the login page, where he/she will need to re-enter the username/password again.

Has anyone else managed to get this working? Most other solutions seems to be implemented with Identityserver3.

Comment: Apart from ease of use: why would you do this? I would like to know for sure that the email address my user entered is actually his or hers before letting him into the system for several reasons: the credentials could be sent to a wrong address (typo) and breached as soon as the registration is done, or someone can use an address that's not theirs to annoy someone, or password reset will never work because of a typo in the address, or ......

Comment: @RickvandenBosch Some systems are quite blase about verified email accounts. Reddit for example would log you in after registration. And Reddit as part of their business requirements see this barrier to entry better for their product than asking people to verify their emails. It just depends on your use case. tl;dr how critical are valid emails in your domain vs how badly do you want a low friction registration process? I would guess that this toss up might guide OPs decision  to go in this route in some way.

Comment: @RickvandenBosch Valid point, but the registration process is actually multiple steps. At this point the user has already confirmed the email address.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is sign in the user in the registration action within your controller responsible for this. In other words you treat your registration controller method in a similar to how you treat your login controller method using this method:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync()
```

This method essentially prepares the `HttpContext` to issue your browser with a cookie when you return the appropriate `IActionResult` from it. I'm sure you've seen [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L95) or something like it. Just do the same thing in the registration method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are you sure that this can be done in the client application, and not just in identityServer?